# Moving postgresql data cluster

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Our postgres data folder was installed on a drive with very limited space. I'm now trying to move it over to a newly mounted drive (more space).  I've followed several blog posts and they all say...

1. stop service
2. copy data cluster
3. update postgresql-9.1 file (PGDATA=)
4. restart service

The service starts but when I go to connect, it gives me "could not connect to server: Connection refused"

I tried telnet-ing to port 5432 and nothing.

Here is the link to what I've been trying:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21324272

Comment: Sounds like postmaster is not running. Check your ps output to verify. Perhaps there's a typo in your new PGDATA path and it's unable to start.

Comment: When I run "start postgresql-9.1 start" I get a [OK].. I'll check postmaster.

Comment: When I run "ps ax | grep postmaster" Looks like it is running.

Comment: I meant the output of the ps command -- like your grep example. In that case, I'd say check your postgresql.conf file to be sure that your `listen_address` and `port` directives are not commented out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.  Looks like the problem was with permissioning.

Instead of doing

```
cp -R fromfolder tofolder
```

I did

```
cp -a fromfolder tofolder
```

And that solved it.  Thanks all.