# How to operate a postgres database from 1 hard disk on multiple systems?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

My issue is that I work from various systems yet require access to a single, large (50 Gb) database that is always up to date. If it were a smaller database, dumping and restoring the database onto the external disk would by fine, e.g. [via](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgdump.html) `$ pg_dump mydb > /path../db.sql` to save it and then on the other computer use `$psql -d mydb -f /path../db.sql` to recover the data and so on...

In this case, however, that option will not work as I don't have 50 Gb of free space on both machines. So I'd like the files for this particular db to be on a single external drive.

How would I do this?

I've been using `pg_cltcluster` for this purpose, e.g.

```
$ cp -rp ax/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main /media/newdest # move the data
$ pg_cltcluster 9.1 main stop # stop the postgres server (on ubuntu: add -- [ctl args])
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/initdb -D /media/newdest # initialise instance in new place
```

(On ubuntu, [pg_ctlcluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man8/pg_ctlcluster.8.html) is used instead of pg_ctl to allow multiple db clusters and this should allow `pg_ctlcluster 9.1 main start -- -D /media/newdest` to replace the last line of code, I think)

I suspect this approach is not the best solution because a) it's not working at present after various tries and b) I'm not sure I'll be able to access the cluster from another computer.

Database software are designed to handle large datasets and moving your data around is a common task so I am baffled about why there is less info on this on the internet:

- This [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41938/seeting-up-a-postgresql-database-on-another-hard-drive-than-my-system-one-on-os) that basically says "don't use TABLESPACES to do it"
- This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265540/moving-postgresql-data-cluster) that just solves the permissions problem and links to a (useful) [IMB](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21324272) page on the matter that talks about moving the *entire* setup, not just one database as I want to.

Comment: Why don't you run the database on one system, and allow the other systems to connect to it over the net?

Comment: Could do - pretty good suggestion. The only downsides I can see would be when I want to access the db on my laptop and there's no internet and slow speed when accessing large chunks of data from it.

Comment: *"moving your data around is a common task"* Not really. Not when you're using a client/server dbms like PostgreSQL. (Or SQL Server, or Oracle, or DB2, or Informix, or Sybase . . . .)